# ServerSocket not binding to port

Tags: java, sockets, port

I have a server code that tries to obtain a free port according to a given port range -

```
private ServerSocket allocatePort() throws IOException {
    ServerSocket server = null;
    for (int i=0; i<serverPortRange; i++) {
        int port = serverPort.intValue()+i;
        try {
            server = new ServerSocket(port);
            break;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            log.debug(String.format("DCServer could not allocate port %s", port));
        }
    }
    if (server == null) {
        throw new IOException();
    }
    return server;
}
```

When two servers run this code on the same machine they somehow get the same port. I checked with netstat if it was actually obtained, and I don't see it in the list of occupied ports.

Any ideas?

Thanks,
Ofir

Comment: Replace line 6 in your code with these 3 lines: server = new ServerSocket(); server.setReuseAddress(true); server.bind(new InetSocketAddress("127.0.0.1", port)); Simply using new ServerSocket(port) is not very stable across JRE-releases and os-platforms.

Comment: Thanks, I tried your suggestion but still not getting the port bounded.

Comment: Are two clients running this code concurrently ? If yes then did'nt any one of the client logged an error in log ? because two ServerSockets on the same machine can't be bounded to same Port at a time.

Comment: Why does a client need a listening port? That's for servers.

Comment: Setting reuseAddress=true is contrary to the expressed intention of the question, so this is not an answer. The rest is nonsense. Binding to 127.0.0.1 is not necessary unless you want to restrict who can connect, which also isn't mentioned in the question, and binding to INADDR_ANY, which is the default, is extremely 'stable', contrary to your claim. -1

Comment: @EJP you are correct. This is a client in my product topology, but in this case it acts as a server. I'll rephrase the question, thanks :)

Comment: @VishalK no log is being generated. Perhaps you can suggest as to which log I should be looking for? Furthermore, when I debug this code, the SocketServer doesn't throw an Exception, so I'm not sure there is anything to log here.

Comment: By log i mean this line written in your code : `log.debug(String.format("DCServer could not allocate port %s", port));` . What i wanted to say that **Two serverSockets can't be bounded to same port number at the same time.** So while executing your code One of the two programs running **concurrently** must have thrown `java.net.BindException` and the catch block is executed where you debugged the output using `log.debug`. And if you want to check the port occupation use the command `netstat -an` on command prompt.

Answer (score 0):

This can Java do for you as the [doc stated](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/ServerSocket.html#ServerSocket%28int%29):

> Creates a server socket, bound to the specified port. A port of 0
>   creates a socket on any free port.

Comment: Thanks, I'm aware of this functionality, but in this case I'm actually interested in providing a specific range for the server socket to try.